# TypeScript commands are not working even after installation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have installed TypeScript from my command prompt using the

```
npm install -g typescript
```

command. After installation, I wrote

```
tsc --version
```

to check its version but that didn't work. tsc commands aren't working even after installing TypeScript.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: [Please check these](https://www.google.com/search?q=tsc+--version+does+not+work+npm+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Out of curiosity - can you see typescript or tsc when you run `$ npm list -g --depth 0` in the command line?

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what exactly do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install typescript globally with npm, `tsc --version` should work, but I've had issues with this - I believe this might be something with the local NPM environment.

Try

`$ npx tsc --version`

and

`$ npx tsc --init`

as per the Typescript download instructions at https://www.typescriptlang.org/download.

EDIT

It seems that with NPX you can locally run packages, which don't get globally installed, but they act like they were (This article explains it pretty well: medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b). This only partially solve your problem, and I suspect that the real reason `tsc` didn't run in your case, is because the global installation didn't work for some reason. When typescript is properly installed globally, `tsc` works.

Run

```
npm install -g typescript
```

and to verify that typescript is installed, run

```
$ npm list -g --depth 0
```

Which will list **typescript** in the globally installed dependencies.

I don't know what exactly causes the issue, but I managed to reproduce the same issue just now - I installed typescript globally with NPM (v12.16.2, NVM v0.33.8), and typescript just didn't install, nor `tsc` was available. I kept trying `npm install -g typescript`, until I could spot typescript in my global dependencies, and from then on `tsc` started working.

Comment: It worked. But how do that work. Why do I have to add npx and other's are just using tsc only.

Comment: @Rupak please see my updated answer, which should better explains the real reason that can cause the issue in your case.

Comment: after installing open new cmd and try

Comment: After installing using ' npm install -g typescript
 ' command, I used the ' npm list -g --depth 0' command. It showed C:\Usr\local
`-- typescript@4.2.3 . But when I did ' tsc -v ' it showed: 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.